# Can generalised momentum be defined as mass times generalised velocity？

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, momentum, coordinate-systems, velocity, definition

The generalised [momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum) is defined by the partial derivative of Lagrangian.  Can we think of this as a mass times a generalised velocity?

Answer (score 2):

The definition $p = m\dot q$ isn't equivalent to $p=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}$, with one counterexample being angle $\phi$ and angular momentum which for a point particle with Lagrangian $L = \frac12 mr^2\dot\phi^2$ is $p_\phi = \frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot\phi} = mr\dot\phi$. Although the formula doesn't exactly correspond to "momentum = mass * velocity", the definition of generalized momentum as the derivative of the Lagrangian with respect to generalized velocity is consistent with the idea of $F = \frac{\mathrm d p}{\mathrm d t}$ and that momentum is conserved in the absence of a net force: $\frac{\partial L}{\partial q} = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}$, where $\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}$ is the generalized force.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you think about momentum, you might picture it as just mass times velocity. But it gets a bit more complicated than that. You see, when we're talking about generalized momentum, it's not always going to be that simple. This kind of momentum can actually be affected by things like the potential energy or non-conservative forces.